# Subqueries in dapper no longer working

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using dapper, I just implemented the splitOn function to get a location object set in my AdListingSearchResult, but by doing so my subqueries (MainPhotoFileName and TotalPhotos) are now null and 0 respectively. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
var data = GetConnection().Query<AdListingSearchResult, AdListingLocationSearchResult, AdListingSearchResult>(@"
SELECT TOP 10 a.AdListingID, a.Title, a.Details, a.CreateDateTime, l.LocationID, l.CountryID, l.USCity, l.USStateCode, l.IntlRegion, c.CountryName,  
(SELECT TOP 1 ap.Filename FROM tbAdListingPhotos ap WHERE ap.AdListingID = a.AdListingID) AS MainPhotoFileName, 
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbAdListingPhotos ap WHERE ap.AdListingID = a.AdListingID) AS TotalPhotos
FROM tbAdListing a 
INNER JOIN tbLocation l ON (a.LocationID = l.LocationID) 
INNER JOIN tbEnumCountry c ON (l.CountryID = c.CountryID) 
WHERE a.Deleted = 0  ORDER BY a.CreateDateTime DESC                 
", (a, l) =>
 {
     a.Location = l;
     return a;
 },
 splitOn: "LocationId"
 ).AsQueryable();

return data;
```

Comment: Which object has the `MainPhotoFileName` (etc) properties? the `AdListingSearchResult`? or the `AdListingLocationSearchResult`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing these sub-queries are meant to map to properties on the `AdListingSearchResult` object. However, the row is partitioned horizontally according to the `splitOn` parameter, which means that `AdListingSearchResult` never sees those values.

You should be able to simply re-order the SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 10 a.AdListingID, a.Title, a.Details, a.CreateDateTime,
(SELECT TOP 1 ap.Filename FROM tbAdListingPhotos ap WHERE ap.AdListingID = a.AdListingID) AS MainPhotoFileName, 
(SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tbAdListingPhotos ap WHERE ap.AdListingID = a.AdListingID) AS TotalPhotos,
l.LocationID, l.CountryID, l.USCity, l.USStateCode, l.IntlRegion, c.CountryName
FROM tbAdListing a
...
```

Comment: I was actually thinking about that today. I will give that a shot and report back shortly. Thanks!

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. I just needed to reorder my select statement.